# Characteristic Variety of the Principal Symbol solves PDE system?

Tags: differential-equations, d-modules, pseudo-differential-operators, micro-local-analysis

In the study of partial differential equations, it is often considered enough to analyze the principal symbols and their characteristic variety (see for example, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870802000993, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_of_a_differential_operator).  In the first link, only the principal symbol is used to count the number of solutions to a holonomic system.  But there are easy examples for which this information does not appear to be enough.  Consider the two-dimensional system:
$$
(\partial+1)\phi(z,z')=0
$$
$$
(\partial+\partial')\phi(z,z')=0
$$
and,
$$
(\partial+z)\psi(z,z')=0
$$
$$
(\partial+\partial')\psi(z,z')=0.
$$
Both have the same principal symbols, namely, $p$ and $p+p'$, however, the first has the solution $\phi(z,z')=e^{z'-z}$, while the second has no solution (other than $\psi(z,z')=0$).

It seems to be suggested in the first link that the second has a solution on an integral curve, perhaps, but it is not clear to me if that is the right context and if so, how does one construct such a curve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*This really should be a comment, but it was too long.*)

Part of the problem is that when you're dealing with a *system* of (linear) PDE's, the principal symbol is not the "right" object. Instead, you want to look at the characteristic ideal. It's defined as follows:

Let $D$ be the ring of linear partial differential operators in $z_1,\ldots,z_n$. A system of PDE's may be viewed as an $r\times s$ matrix $\mathsf P$ with entries in $D$. Let $N$ be the left column space of $\mathsf P$, i.e. the left $D$-module generated by the columns of $\mathsf{P}$. Let $\operatorname{gr}(D)=\{\sigma_P\mid P\in D\}$ be the (commutative) ring of principal symbols of differential operators, and let $\operatorname{gr}(N)=\{\sigma_V\mid V\in N\}$ be the $\operatorname{gr}(D)$-module of principal symbols of $N$. The *characteristic ideal* of the system of PDE's is (the radical of) the ideal
$$ \operatorname{Ann}_{\operatorname{gr}(D)}\bigl(\operatorname{gr}(D)^r/\operatorname{gr}(N)\bigr).$$ 
The reason we need to take the radical is because the un-radicalized ideal depends on choice of coordinates while its radical does not.

There's a coordinate-free definition, but it's a bit more involved to state.

**Edit: In your case:**
System 1: Have $r=1$ and $N=D\{\partial+1, \partial +\partial'\} $. One can show using Gröbner basis theory that $\operatorname{gr}(N)=(\partial, \partial') $.

System 2: Have $r=1$ and $N=D\{\partial+z, \partial +\partial'\} $. You might guess that $\operatorname{gr}(N)$ would be the same, but you'd be wrong! In fact, notice that the commutator  $[ \partial +\partial', \partial+z] $ is $1$, so $N=D $, and in particular $\operatorname{gr}(N)= \operatorname{gr}(D) $.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on this?  How would it look in the current problem?  I am a physicist, so I'm afraid I may need it spelled out a bit more.  Specifically, I don't understand what the Ann function represents.

Comment: @alphanzo Ann is called the annihilator. It consists of all the elements of the ring which kill the entire module. The radical of an ideal $I$ is the set of ring elements $f$ such that $f^k\in I$ for some $k\geq1$.

Comment: Thank you for this insight!  This is very interesting and I'd like to read more if you can provide a reference.  In this case, is it true that $r\times s=1\times 2$, so that the Characteristic ideal is simply $(p,\ p+p')=(0,0)$, which is itself isomorphic the Characteristic variety, $Ch(M)\subset T^*X$ for the module $M=D_X/I$, for $I=D_X(\partial+\beta(x))+D_X(\partial+\partial')$...?

Comment: A good reference for the case of diffops on $\Bbb C^n$ with polynomial coefficients is Gröbner Deformations of Hypergeometric Differential Equations by Sato, Sturmfels, and Takayama. As for more general situations, any basic text on D-modules will cover this, probably under a section on characteristic varieties (the variety in the cotangent space cut out by the characteristic ideal) of coherent D-modules. For these, though, you'll want to be comfortable with sheaf language.

Comment: Another reasonable reference is Chapter 17 of "Twenty-Four Hours of Local Cohomology" by Iyengar, et. al. It does have a few mistakes, in section 1 (the only not-easily-identified one is that Remark 17.7 holds if $R$ is a polynomial ring but not in general), though they don't affect the rest of the chapter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I just discovered Gröbner's book while looking into it, so I'll check that one out first.  I'm still stumped on this problem, though, since it would seem that even your advice amounts to looking at the principle symbols, yet, supposedly there is no nontrivial solution unless one drops the $z$ term, which is something that cannot be inferred from the principle symbol.  Am I wrong that this system is holonomic?  And if it's holonomic, shouldn't it have a nonzero solution?

Comment: I just came here to point out that, indeed,  the ideal $I=D_X(\partial+x)+D_X(\partial+\partial')$ does not define a holonomic D-module because the Gr\"obner basis  is not spanned by only two elements.  The obstruction is that the pair does not form an S-pair (as in the reference you pointed to), which is akin to saying that the system is not involutive.  I saw your edit before I could type it, so I'm awarding you the points for the most thorough answer, though I'm grateful to everyone who commented.

Comment: @alphanzo I think you're confused about what holonomic means and what Gröbner basis means. They have absolutely nothing to do with one another. Gröbner bases are a calculation tool—if you have a Gröbner basis $G$ of an ideal $I$, the principal symbols of $G$ generate $\operatorname{gr}(I)$. You are correct that the given generating set for the second system is not a Gröbner basis. However, it's still considered holonomic. Holonomic simply means that the characteristic variety (i.e. The variety in the cotangent bundle cut out by the characteristic ideal) had dimension at most $n$.

Comment: In Sato's book on Gröbner bases he seems to define holonomicity by the requirement that the initial ideal in$_{(0,1)}(I)$ has dimension at most $n$.  But doesn't the Gröbner basis span in$_{(0,1)}(I)$?  (Edit: Ah, I see, it spans $gr(I)$ while in$_{(0,1)}(I)\subset gr(I)$ are the highest weights).

The reason I would like to say this system is not holonomic is because I was under the impression that a holonomic system is also involutive... isn't that what Kashiwara has shown?

Comment: @alphanzo You're correct that a holonomic system (or more precisely it's characteristic variety) must be involutive. That's actually true of all coherent D-modules. A nonzero holonomic guy is in addition Lagrangian. We need to allow $0$ to also be holonomic (even though its characteristic variety is empty) so that the category of holonomic D-modules is abelian. That's why the second system is still considered holonomic. Incidentally, your second system actually no non-trivial solutions.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say that the Gröbner basis has nothing to say about holonomicity.  For example, if the cotangent space $T^*X$ has dimension 4, and the   Gröbner basis has dimension three then wouldn't it follow that $in_{(0,1)}(I)$ has three generators as well?  In the generic case it seems very unlikey that this system is holonomic unless a miracle occurs, and the zeros in the third equation are dependent on the other two.

Comment: @alphanzo that's not a fact about Gröbner bases per se. It's what's called Krull's Altitude Theorem, and it says that the variety of an ideal in a polynomial ring has dimension at most the minimal number of generators of the ideal.

Answer (score 12):

The Wikipedia page that you cite contains the mistake that it does not distinguish between determined and overdetermined systems (as yours are), or, rather, more importantly, it does not distinguish between *involutive* systems (as your first one is) and *noninvolutive* ones (as your second one is).   In overdetermined or symbol-degenerate cases (i.e., systems in which every co-direction is characteristic), the principal symbol alone does not contain enough information to determine whether the system is involutive or not, and this has an even greater effect on the nature of the solutions than does the principal symbol.  The author of that page probably only had the determined, nondegenerate case in mind while writing it.

As usual with information found on the Internet, *caveat lector*.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That is indeed the correct way to go about it in the Frobenius picture when the equations are linear.  However, in the second link the general case is considered *micro locally*.   It seems  that the second system does have a solution if only in the micro local sense of the term. I'm wondering if it implies there exists a hypersurface M⊂C2 on which a solution exists for restricted values (z,z′)∈M?

Comment: First, involutivity has nothing to do with linearity; they are independent notions.  Second, I don't know what it means to have a solution 'in the micro-local sense', so I can't help you there.  What's certainly true is that there are solution *curves* in both cases (i.e., 1-dimensional integral manifolds in the space of $1$-jets), but the only $2$-dimensional integral manifold in the second case is the one given by the (unique) solution $\psi = 0$.

Comment: @RobertBryant can you please elaborate on what involutivity means in this sense?

Comment: @Bran:  For the case in hand, a solution of the first system is a $2$-dimensional integral manifold of the $1$-form $\theta_1 = \mathrm{d}\phi+\phi\,\mathrm{d}z-\phi\,\mathrm{d}z'$ while a solution of the second system is a $2$-dimensional integral manifold of the $1$-form $\theta_2 = \mathrm{d}\phi+z\phi\,\mathrm{d}z-z\phi\,\mathrm{d}z'$. Both $1$-forms have integral curves, but $\theta_1=0$ is `involutive' while $\theta_2=0$ is not 'involutive' in the sense of $2$-plane fields.  Does that help?

Comment: @RobertBryant yes, clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let me elaborate a little about what Robert wrote. When analyzing a system of PDE's, there are two separate issues that need to be considered. Below, I'll assume that you want to study the space of smooth solutions to a homogeneous linear system of PDE's.

Before you even look at the characteristic variety (i.e., study the system microlocally), you have to look at the formal properties of the system. In other words, are there any formal power series solutions (without considering convergence) to the system? If there aren't any, then there's no point in going any further. If there are, the next important question is how "many" formal solutions are there?

Figuring this out is not always easy, especially with an overdetermined system like yours. Note that each of your systems has 2 unknown real-valued functions but 4 real-valued equations. As Robert says, the two systems have completely different formal properties. To analyze them properly, you often have to do what's known as prolongation which involves adding more unknown functions and equations obtained by differentiating the original equations. To determine whether you have formal solutions and "how many", you have to keep doing this until the system satisfies a condition known as involutivity.

Only after you have an involutive system does the characteristic variety (or ideal or sheaf) of the involutive system (and not the original system) tell you anything meaningful about the system of PDE's.

In your examples, the symbol and therefore the characteristic (variety, ideal, sheaf) are the same for both systems. However, since the second one is not involutive, the characteristic object tells you nothing about the second system. However, if you prolong the second system until it becomes involutive, then the characteristic object of the prolonged system will tell you something about the second system of PDE's and its solutions. In particular, they will be different from those of the first system.

The theory for this is quite involved. I'll let others provide more specific references for all of this.